# Create Excel with style with JasperReports

Tags: java, excel, pdf, jasper-reports

I'm working with JasperReports 3.2. I have a report that I export to PDF and Excel. The report uses custom styles introduced by the user. I parse the styles in Java as it's explained [here](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/samples/StyledTextReport.html). so a sample text from the report before being interpreted is

```
Test<style isBold="true" pdfFontName="verdanab.ttf">Test Bold</style> Some text <style isItalic="true" pdfFontName="verdanai.ttf">Test Italic</style>
```

While this work on the PDF (the text shows styles) the xls file just ignore the style tags. I have created the report in iReport 3. I checked the box that says "Is Styled Text" and tried all the markup styles availables (RTF, HTML and None) but I can't produce the styled xls.

Do you know a how to get this working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use some sort of workaround: Created the report as html instead of xls and send it to the user as "xxx.xls" so the Excel opens it. It worked for this situation.